# Prove the intersection of events to be 1

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

$B_n$, $n$ from $1$ to infinity is countably infinite sequence of events and each event has probability $1$. How do I formally prove that the probability of intersection of $B_n$ from $n = 1$ to infinity is also $1$. Intuitively I know because $P[B_i] = 1$, so all events are equivalent to the total sample space, and so does its intersection. But how to prove it in formal way?

Comment: "*All events are equivalent to the total sample space*" is false if by "equivalent" you mean *equal to*.  They will be *equal in measure*, but this is different than being equal.

Comment: @JMoravitz: Even in terms of measure, the measure on the sample space for each event is simply not the same as the measure on the whole sample space over all events. So the 'intuition' stated in the question is still meaningless to me.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1745912/21820 for a counter-example when uncountably many events are allowed, which shows that your stated intuition is wrong somehow.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**: The probability of at least one of the events not happening is at most the sum of the probabilities of each event not happening, which is zero because there are only countably many of them each with probability zero of not happening.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{align}
1 \ge \mathbb{P}\left(\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}B_n \right)
= 1 - \mathbb{P}\left(\left[\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}B_n\right]^c \right)
= 1 - \mathbb{P}\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}B^c_n \right)
\ge 1 - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(B^c_n)
= 1
\end{align}
$$