# $\aleph_1$ almost sure events that almost never all hold

Tags: probability-theory, set-theory

[This recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1745841/21820) sparked my curiosity. Is there a family of events $(E_k)_{k \in I}$ such that$\def\pp{\mathbb{P}}$ $\pp(E_k) = 1$ for any $k \in I$ but $\pp( \bigcap_{k \in I} E_k ) = 0$? Clearly any such family must be uncountable, and my intuition tells me that it exists, so I proceeded to try constructing one.

Let $X \sim U([0,1])$, and let $E_r = ( X \ne r )$ for each $r \in [0,1]$. Then $\pp(E_r) = 1$ for any $r \in [0,1]$, but $\pp( \bigcap_{r \in [0,1]} E_r ) = 0$.

So now my question is, is there a family of size $\aleph_1$ (that ZFC proves has the above property)?

At first I meant my question to be general, where one is allowed to choose any maximal probability measure (non-negative, total measure 1, countable additivity, cannot be extended) based on which all the events are defined. But Eric's comment suggests that the question may be non-trivial even for the Lebesgue measure on a Euclidean space. So I'm now interested in both variants. =)

Comment: What is your exact definition of "family of events"?  If you're allowed to pick the probability space to be whatever you want, you can get an example (just take a set of size $\aleph_1$ where only countable and cocountable sets are measurable).  But if you're required to use the standard probability space, I'm pretty sure this is independent of ZFC.

Comment: @EricWofsey: Haha I thought that the "set-theory" tag was reserved for advanced set theory. What do you mean by "the standard probability space"? I'd like a maximal probability measure, but I don't know what a "standard" one would be on an arbitrary sample space.

Comment: By "standard" I meant Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$, or any other probability space that is essentially equivalent (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_probability_space).

Comment: @EricWofsey: Oh that's what you meant. But I'd be interested to know the answer if you are allowed to choose whatever probability space you want, as long as you provide a maximal probability measure (non-negative, total measure 1, countable additivity, cannot be extended). However, since your comment suggests that the question is nontrivial even for random variables with support being a subset of Euclidean space, then I'd also be interested in an answer under that more restricted condition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let me just address the question on $\mathbb{R}$.

One way to ask this question is:

> Is there a family of $\aleph_1$-many subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, each of which is Lebesgue null, whose union is all of $\mathbb{R}$?

(I'm interpreting the sets in this phrasing as the *complements* of the events in the question, to match with language used elsewhere.)

It turns out (IIRC) that this is independent of ZFC!

If $\vert\mathbb{R}\vert=\aleph_1$ (the **Continuum Hypothesis**), then the answer is clearly "yes": just take each set to be a singleton!

If $\vert\mathbb{R}\vert>\aleph_1$, the answer is not obviously no; and indeed if I remember correctly, it is consistent that $\vert\mathbb{R}\vert=\aleph_2$ and $\mathbb{R}$ is the union of $\aleph_1$-many null sets.

A related question is:

> What is the smallest number of null sets, whose union is non-null?

(Here "null" refers to the usual Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$.) This number, $\mathfrak{m}$, is a **cardinal characteristic of the continuum** (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_characteristic_of_the_continuum#non.28N.29 and http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~ablass/hbk.pdf); it is provably uncountable, and provably at most $2^{\aleph_0}$, but consistently we can have $$\aleph_1<\mathfrak{m}<2^{\aleph_0}.$$

Comment: Re: the phrasing of the second question in my answer: Note that any *measurable* non-null subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}$ definitely has size $2^{\aleph_0}$: by inner regularity, $A$ contains a closed set $C$ of positive measure. Since $C$ has positive measure, $C$ must be uncountable; but uncountable closed sets have size continuum.

Comment: I didn't know that it is consistent with ZFC that $\mathbb{R}$ is bigger than $\aleph_1$ but is a union of $\aleph_1$ Lebesgue-null sets. Any reference for that? And do you have any idea for the original question regarding the unrestricted case? Your related question is way beyond me haha..

Comment: I happened to come back here, and accepted your answer since there is no other. =)