# Convergence of composition of random variables

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Suppose that $X_n, n=1,\dots$ is a sequence of $\mathcal{X}$-valued random variables.

Suppose further that for all $y \in \mathcal{Y}$ we have $g(y,X_n) \overset{c}{\to} h(y)$, where $h: \mathcal{Y} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $g: \mathcal{Y} \times \mathcal{X} \to \mathbb{R}$ are measurable functions; and $\overset{c}{\to}$ denotes the type of convergence.

> What are the least additional assumptions that guarnatee $g(Y,X_n) \overset{c}{\to} h(Y)$, where $c$ denotes convergence "almost surely" or "in probability"?

<s>**Remark**. With the current assumptions we can construct counter-examples such that the convergence does not hold. Consider almost sure convergence. The hypothesis says that</s>

$$
\forall y. \Pr\left\{ \omega \mid \forall \varepsilon. \exists N(\epsilon,y). \forall n > N(\epsilon, y). \lvert g(y,X_n(\omega)) - h(y) \rvert < \varepsilon \right\} = 1
$$

and we require

$$
\Pr\left\{ \omega \mid \forall \varepsilon. \exists N(\epsilon). \forall n > N(\epsilon). \lvert g(Y(\omega),X_n(\omega)) - h(Y(\omega)) \rvert < \varepsilon \right\} = 1
$$

which may not hold if say $N(\epsilon,y) = y + 1/\epsilon$ and $\mathcal{Y}$ is countable.

Comment: If $\mathcal{Y}$ is finite or countable then with $c=\text{almost sure convergence}$ the result holds without additional assumptions, I'm pretty sure. I don't understand your comment about $N(\epsilon,y)=y+1/\epsilon$ and I don't think a counterexample can exist

Comment: I see, in my supposed counter-example, it would suffice to let $N(\epsilon) = N(\varepsilon, Y(\omega))$.

Comment: @FShrike what counter-example do you have in mind for a.s. convergence with $\mathcal{Y}$ uncountable?

Comment: I don't have a counterexample in mind. I just noted that if $\mathcal{Y}$ is countable, we can intersect all of the almost sure subsets to obtain another almost sure subset on which the convergence of $g(Y,X_n)$ is guaranteed

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1745912/aleph-1-almost-sure-events-that-almost-never-all-hold